# Access window object from a different js file

Tags: javascript, web, web-worker

I have a web worker that generates pdf of a table and post it on the main js file. The code is something like this

worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    var pdf = window.generatePdf();
    postMessage(e.data[0]);
}
```

main.js

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage([config]);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  save(e.data);
}
```

But window object can no be accessed in worker.js file. Any idea on how to make it accessible in that file or how to achieve the functionality otherwise. Thanks.

Edit: I am using pdfmake.min.js to generate pdf file. Can this file be accessed from within worker.js?

Comment: try to send `window` object too as a param?

Comment: @syedfaizan I tried that. But it throws data cloning error.Seems like object with functions can't be cloned in this fashion.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Any other way to do this. Actually the pdf is is quite large,so I am trying to generate it in background thread.